# workflow manager custom activity base class derived from codeactivity

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow

I have a problem with a custom acivity based on Sharepoint Workflow environment.
I'ld like to extend CodeActivity class by OOP.

In simplified form, like this (just a sample):

```c#
public class RestApiBasedActivity : CodeActivity
{
  public InArgument<string> Url { get; set;}
  public OutnArgument<string> Error { get; set;}

  protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
  {
    RestApiCall(Convert.ToString(this.Url));
  }
  public virtual void RestApiCall(string url)
  {
    ....
  }
}


public sealed class MyExactActivity : RestApiBasedActivity
{
  public override void RestApiCall(string url)
  {
    // call some method
    base.RestApiCall(url);
  }
}
```

MyExactActivity exists in files AllowedTypes.xml and CustomActivities.actions4.

MyExactActivity works fine and as an Action can be shown in Sharepoint Designer.

When I try to put it on a workflow choosen from Activities, then Sharepoint Designer can't insert it.

I do not really understand why Action insert fallen?
I can't find any log information in ULS log and Event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunatelly the activity works whenit inherits CodeActivity class not directly, but Sharepoint Designer can't use it. I think it's a Sharepoint Designer bug.